# How to add SchemaValidation to JAX-WS RI client

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

There's this [guide](https://metro.java.net/guide/ch04.html#client-side-schema-validation) which explains how to do it. I take it that is still the "official" way to do it even if I'm using the JAX-WS bundled into the JDK? Here's the highlight of what is recommended:

```
import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidationFeature;

SchemaValidationFeature feature = new SchemaValidationFeature();
HelloPort port = new HelloService.getHelloPort(feature);
```

In any case - to make this work with JAX-RS bundled with the JDK - one has to import `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer.SchemaValidationFeature`. However when I compile I get

```
package com.sun.xml.internal.ws.developer does not exist
```

The reason is that - although the class exists in the JDK - it is not on the whitelist (as expressed by the JDK's `lib/ct.sym` file) so the compiler will complain.

This seems like a catch22. The official guide tells me to do it using SchemeValidationFeature class, yet in real life I cannot actually access this class.

I can of course turn off the use of the class whitelist (i.e. `ignore.symbol.file=true`) on the compile step but this shouldn't be necessary when following an official recommandation from Oracle about how to enable a specific feature in the JDK itself. Hence I'm assuming there's something wrong the recipe I'm following.

To restate the question:  What is the official recommendation for how to enable schema validation on a web service client using the JAX-WS which is bundled with the JDK ? .. .and how to make it work ?